# select properties of T if they match a column name in a datatable and ignore case

Tags: c#, linq

i have a part of a generic function where i need to copy property info to a list only if its name matches one of the datatable columns.

```
    DataTable dt = new DataTable();
    .
    .
    .
//here i want only the properties that have the same name of some column in the datatable
    List<PropertyInfo> properties = typeof(T).GetProperties().ToList();
```

how can i do this using LINQ?

i tried

```
List<PropertyInfo> properties = typeof(T).GetProperties().Where(p=> dt.Columns.Contains(p.Name)).ToList();
```

but it doesnt seem to work that way, because i need to ignore case on both sides property name and column name

problem with ToUpper() and ToLower() functions is some times the column names are not totally lower case nor upper case

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try something like this:

```
List<PropertyInfo> properties = typeof(T).GetProperties().Where(p => dt.Columns.Cast<DataColumn>().Any(c => c.ColumnName.Equals(p.Name, StringComparison.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase))).ToList();
```

Comment: Please consider looking carefully to the answer and you'll notice that it fits the requirement very well.